# Large file copy causing user threads to not get scheduled on CPU

Tags: files, filesystem, ssd, btrfs

We are running Xenial (16.04) with Linux kernel 4.15.0-36-generic and running a script that does the below in a loop

1. Copy file from one location to another on disk.
2. SFTP the above file to an external server

Ubuntu rootfs is running btrfs and the size of the file being copied is typically around 2GB.

We see that there is a high latency in the user-level threads when the script is active on the system. 
The delay is in the range of 1sec-3sec. If the file size is increased to 10GB, the thread latency is in the range of 10-20sec

More details:

The disk type is SSD and system has 64GB RAM. Btrfs filesystems mounted using the below options:

```
rw,noatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache
```

The VM sysctl options are

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200
```

What we want is that the disk activity should not freeze the user threads as they are critical for us.

Update with more information:

Adding more information. When we modify the sysctl VM options to something aggressive(below), the situation gets better.

```
sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=1
sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=2
sysctl -w vm.dirty_expire_centisecs=1000
sysctl -w vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs=100
```

Does it make sense to have the above settings? Or do we need to change the IO scheduler to something other than the default [CFQ]?

Comment: What does `top` show?

Comment: The cp command takes around 2-3 seconds to copy the 2GB file and the SFTP takes around 4-5 minutes. The CPU usages of those processes in top o/p go in the range of 30-50%. When we copy over a 15GB files, the CP process takes around 1.5min and issue is more frequent. Added an update to the main description.